# Pearson's Coefficient and Covariance calculation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation, pearson

I want to calculate [Pearson's correlation coefficent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) in Matlab (without using Matlab's `corr` function).

Simply, I have two vectors A and B (each of them is 1x100) and I am trying to calculate the Pearson's coefficient like this:

```
P = cov(x, y)/std(x, 1)std(y,1)
```

I am using Matlab's `cov` and `std` functions. What I don't get is, the cov function returns me a square matrix like this:

```
corrAB =
    0.8000    0.2000
    0.2000    4.8000
```

But I expect a single number as the covariance so I can come up with a single P (pearson's coefficient) number. What is the point I'm missing?

Comment: Do you mean `P = cov(x,y)/sqrt(var(x)*var(y));`?  The diagonal should be 1.  The off diagonal is what you want.

Comment: you are right, I updated the question. Is the "off diagonal" in above example are 0.2000 and 0.2000? So should I do another calculation with them or just go with 0.2?

Comment: In you're example, 0.2 is the off diagonal.  However, the 0.8 and 4.8 should both be 1.  So something is wrong with your calc.  Just do corr(x,y) to check.  Read the help to understand why it returns a matrix.  It was unexpected to me the first time also.

Comment: My arrays are like: x =[4 5 5 3 5], y = [4 4 0 0 0]. Maybe because of that, there are values like 4.8. I'll read the docs, thanks.

Comment: @RichC: the diagonals need not be 1. The will be 1 only if the variances of both samples are exactly the same.

Comment: @yoda: you're right.  I was thinking P was the correlation matrix, but only the off diagonal elements are correct.  The diagonal elements are nonsense.

Comment: @RichC: the diagonal elements are not nonsense... they are the variances of `x` and `y` :)

Comment: @yoda: the diagonals of P as defined above are nonsense.

Comment: @RichC: There's some confusion here. The matrix output, `corrAB` that Ramala gave in the question is correct, and the diagonals are the variances. As for the matrix `P` that he defined (denominator needs to be enclosed in parenthesis), the diagonals are `sigma_x/sigma_y` and `sigma_y/sigma_x` respectively. Still not nonsense, as its a direct measure of how much the deviation in one sample is, compared to the other.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're just confused with covariance and covariance matrix, and the mathematical notation and MATLAB's function inputs do look similar. In math, `cov(x,y)` means the **[covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)** of the two variables `x` and `y`. In MATLAB, `cov(x,y)` calculates the **[covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix)** of `x` and `y`. Here `cov` is a function and `x` and `y` are the inputs.

Just to make it clearer, let me denote the covariance by `C`. MATLAB's `cov(x,y)` returns a matrix of the form

```
C_xx    C_xy
C_yx    C_yy
```

As RichC pointed out, you need the off-diagonals, `C_xy` (note that `C_xy=C_yx` for real variables `x` and `y`). A MATLAB script that gives you the Pearson's coefficient for two variables `x` and `y`, is:

```
C=cov(x,y);
p=C(2)/(std(x)*std(y));
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> cov(X,Y), where X and Y are matrices
>   with the same number of elements, is
>   equivalent to cov([X(:) Y(:)]).

use:

```
C = cov(X,Y);
coeff = C(1,2) / sqrt(C(1,1) * C(2,2))
```

Comment: Is the "coeff" variable is Pearson coefficient? or you meant covariance? Because in the coefficient formula, I need to divide the covariance by standart deviations of X and Y.