# Need to calculate Pearson Coefficient using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors A & B, and both can be (1xn) matrix.

Will the below code still work:
C=cov(x,y);
p=C(2)/(std(x)*std(y));

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pearson's Coefficient and Covariance calculation in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644981/pearsons-coefficient-and-covariance-calculation-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "vectors [...] can be (1xn) matrix" ... aren't all vectors 1-by-n matrices? Do you mean 'as opposed to n-by-1'? Besides, what is keeping you from simply trying it?

```
>> x=rand(1,100);y=rand(1,100)+x;
>> C=cov(x,y); p=C(2)/(std(x)*std(y))

 p =

     0.6642
```

Looks about right to me...

Alternatively, try this:
`help corrcoef`

Comment: i have x = [1 0 1 0 0 0];
y = [1 1 1 1 1 1]; the value of C(2) is zero in this case. Any idea where I am going wrong

Comment: Nowhere. There is 0 covariance between x and y. (Also, there is 0 variance in y, but this is not a necessary condition. There is also 0 covariance between x and [0 1 1 1 0 0], for example.)